# как по id найти пользователя и обновить допустим имя?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
function createTable ( $table = 'client' )
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (

          client_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,              
          client_name VARCHAR(30)

    )";

    return $this->prepare( $sql )->execute();
}
```

вот такая таблица нужно найти по колонке *client_id* =3
и обновить значение колонки *client_name* под этим **id**

что писать в запросе ?

```
$this->prepare("");
```

Comment: [UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: Учебники по sql читали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто подготовить этот запрос

```
$sql = "UPDATE client SET client_name=? WHERE client_id = ?";
```

Comment: да все нормально я использую bindParam